# Checking each line of text in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and unsure of how to do this easily, I'm making a system that checks UUID of each person that runs the script, and if it matches to let it pass

```
import requests
import uuid
def Test():
url = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/HQN6nbMa'
r = requests.get(url)
ontent = r.text
if ontent == str(uuid.getnode()):
    print('You may enter')
else:
    print('Please go away')
```

Currently, it only checks for the first line in the list and not the whole list, I tried a few methods with the split function but that seems to have done nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
For I in r.text:
```

?

Comment: Not too sure how I would use this, one method I tried was actually saving the Pastebin file to a text file and then running a "with open" using some other info I found online, but that failed quite badly too. I'm mostly going off other scripts online and then forming them to my needs... As I said to my post, I don't really know python.

Comment: If the text inside r is multilined then this loop makes it so that every loop it will gather each line and you can whatever you want with I or any other variable name with each loop

Comment: Oh, I see. Alright, I'll see what I can do to use this then, Thank you.

Comment: If it helped you, don't forget to mark this as a correct solution

Comment: I tried using what you said above and it still doesn't work, It just spams the "Please go away"... This seems to have not worked, thanks anyways though.

Comment: Then each line must have something different because I answered your question but not your code